# Capitalized text in UILabel from visual editor in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I am starter in iOS. I found out that there are ways around making the text bold, and changing font and font size etc from visual editor. But are there any ways to set the UILabel **text All Capitalized from visual editor (STORYBOARD, NOT CODE)**. I searched but only found code (Swift/Objective C) based answers like this:

```
testDisplayLabel.text = testDisplayLabel.text.uppercased()
```

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Just **turn ON caps lock and type text** :) that's the way we do in storyboard, Other thing you can do is select a font that has only Uppercase character in it.

Comment: so if we type from keyboard, it wont be caps ?

Comment: If enable caps from it will be caps in Storyboard and if we choose that has only Upper case character then not matter what you type(lowercase or uppercase ) it will be visible as Uppercase text

Comment: So if the text is initially in caps any text we put later will be caps too?

Comment: what method you are choosing ? caps on or font with only uppercase letter ?

Comment: Only upper case, So if I type uppercase with caps lock on it will not print lowercase ?

Comment: YES in mac if "caps on" the character will be Uppercase all the time you type with or without holding swift

Answer (score 5):

A legitimate question -- and a useless (if not arrogant) answer marked as Accepted. It is not unusual when you receive from a copywriter a LOT of text that is not All Caps. So the answer is -- you have to process it all programmatically.

EDIT Generally it is a good idea to wrap your text constants programmatically. First it gives you the opportunity to localize your app (even in the future):

```
extension String {
    func localized (lang: String) -> String {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path (forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj") else { return "" }
        guard let bundle = Bundle (path: path) else { return "" }
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
    }
        
    func localized () -> String {
        guard let loc = Locale.current.languageCode else { return "" }
        return localized(lang: loc)
    }
}
```

So whenever you need to display a string, you apply this method like this:

```
"My String".localized()
```

Likewise, your string should start with a common localisation, and then you make them capitalized when needed:

```
"This should be all caps".localized().uppercased()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default "lowercase word" and "uppercase word" are unbound in Preferences -> Key Bindings -> Text Key Bindings. Just create a new set and bind them to something. Then you will be able to use the binding to capitalize the text.